# Missing ligature in font causing missing text in PDFBox 3.0

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I am having an issue with PDFBox 3.0 that does not happen in PDFBox 2. When displaying text in a loaded TTF font, all occurences of the string 'ft' are replaced with ' '. I've narrowed this down to a ligature for 'ft' missing from the font file. In previous versions this would simply print 'ft' but in 3.0 this is now empty space. Is there any way to switch off ligatures for the font or a fallback so the text will print correctly?

Code sample:

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH_TO_FONT));
contentStream.setFont(font, 20);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.showText("This is a gift message. f t.");
contentStream.endText();
```

This will display 'This is a gi  message. f t.' on the PDF. (This works fine with the built in fonts.)

I have also tried the below with no success:

```
TrueTypeFont ttf = new TTFParser().parse(...);
ttf.disableGsubFeature("liga");
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, ttf, false);
```

Comment: Try to disable ligatures for the font, you can do it setting the rendering mode to `RenderingMode.FILL`.

Comment: Please link to the font, or mention it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Unfortunately I am not able to link to the font. But I can confirm it has an 'ft' ligature which is just an empty space

Comment: @DiegoBorba setting the rendering mode does not disable ligatures for me

Comment: @TilmanHausherr This also has no effect.

Comment: I looked into the code and I couldn't find how to disable it. And worse, I couldn't easily find a way to add this as a feature that could be switched on and off :-(

Comment: Out of curiosity, *"But I can confirm it has an 'ft' ligature which is just an empty space"* - Can you not switch to a font that either has an 'ft' ligature that displays as 'ft', or that has no 'ft' ligature to start with?

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5700 . My feeling is that it's a design flaw. Can you find out whether there is an updated version of that font? Or complain to the vendor?

Comment: @mkl unfortunately it is a proprietary font that must be used. I will contact the vendor in the meantime

Comment: *"unfortunately it is a proprietary font that must be used"* - Have you considered repairing it in a font editor?

Comment: @mkl this appears to be the way forward for now. Thanks